# Linklist with cyclic from third node

Tags: c

i m having a singly linear linklist in which the last is having the address of the third node i.e from from the third node the cycle is made.
I need to count the number of nodes present in the linklist and printout the data part of the nodes... SO HOW CAN I DO IT..??

Comment: please comment if any other method can be used to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You must traverse the list starting from the first node, printing and counting the data items. When you reach the third node you store the pointer to that node in an ancillary pointer variable. You then continue traversing the list until you find that the "next" pointer in node is equal to the ancillary you stored.

Comment: Since we know that the link is to the third node you only have to store that address.

Comment: Thank you, I've missed that fact. I will edit my answer right now.

Comment: thanks for that solution...it worked for this and also for when the list is cyclic from any node.

Comment: more better option which could be used in this type of problem is HASHING. using 2 pointers in which 1 is ahead of another and the previous one saves the addresses of previously visited nodes and front pointer compares all the node addresses with the previously visited nodes which saved in the HASH table.where it gets the same address it will return TRUE otherwise FALSE. that is using boolean here